# add a line break into sql database and php on POST

Tags: php

Just wondering the best way to do this.

Basically I have a message type website. Basically a text area which users can write stories to eachother.

At the moment when i type a story in the text area with paragraphs - for example :

"A while ago I was walking down the road when a dog attacked me.

New paragraph here talking about dogs."

at the moment would post only the first line into mysql database. Is there a way to automatically add 
 or /n for each time the enter key is pressed ?

But not to be visible to the user when typing in the text area.

Thank you

Comment: You can enter new lines in html text areas.  You can then use nl2br for html output, to recreate those line breaks.

Comment: I don't understand why you say you only have the first line of the text area added into the database.  Is this a html text field or a textarea?

Answer (score 1):

You can use text editor like https://www.tinymce.com/ It will automatically manage all special symbols in the text.

Many web frameworks provide such editor components too, see whether your framework has such, otherwise use tinymce it is one of the most popular.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you should already have all line breaks in your db, you might just not display it correctly. Try [nl2br](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.nl2br.php) to display the line breaks

Answer (score 0):

This is a common question which most users have.

When you echo the result from your database, you need to use `nl2br`.

For example, if you your code was `echo $row['story']`, it would have to be `echo nl2br($row['story'])`